# 2D Array from a columned text file in python

Tags: python, arrays, file, numpy

I am new to python and working on a script that will create a 2D array from a text file. The file has 4 columns, like so:

```
P    F    T    S
0    0    0    0.227321
0    0    1    0.0380602
0    0    2    -0.804958
0    0    3    0.271401
```

Where P, F, T, and S are the polarization state, frequency, time, and signal strength, respectively. I want to create a 2D matrix of S such that they will have x and y coordinates of the corresponding T and F values (Ignoring P). I know how to create a matrix from text, but that just creates a 4 by n matrix that is identical in form to the text file. How can I generate the 2D matrix I need?

EDIT: I meant ignoring P, not S.

Comment: its not clear what matrix you're trying to construct.  `F` is always 0 and `T` ranges from 0-3. does this mean you want a (4,1) matrix with only four values in it?  what if there was a value greater than 0 in `F`, what do you want the undefined entries in the matrix to be?

Comment: The file is much longer, there end up being values in F, T, and P.

Comment: .... so is the size of the matrix you want to build determined by the max value found in `T` and `F`?

Comment: Yes, exactly! So each (T,F) will have an S value.

Comment: check my answer, I think it does what you want.  please accept it by clicking the green check if it was helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your text file is named `data.txt`

```
import numpy as np
dat = np.loadtxt( 'data.txt' )
```

now `dat[0,:]` will be the first row and `dat[:,2]` will be the third column and so on.  Note that you will have to add a comment character to the first line `#` of your file so it wont be readin by `loadtxt`.

```
ii = dat[:,1].astype( np.int )  # this is the F column as ints
jj = dat[:,2].astype( np.int )  # this is the T column as ints

nx = max(ii) + 1
ny = max(jj) + 1
d = np.zeros( (nx,ny) )

n = 0
for i,j in zip(ii,jj):
    d[i,j] = dat[n,3]
    n += 1
```

Now `d` will have the values of `S` in the locations specified by the columns `F` and `T` and 0's elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

How about this sample:

```
with open("matrix.txt", "r") as df:
    txt = df.read()
    items = txt.split()
    items = [float(n) for n in items]
    data = zip([i for i in items[1::4]], [i for i in items[2::4]], [i for i in items[3::4]])
    print(data)
    print(data[1][2])
```

Output:

[(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 2.0), (0.0, 3.0)]

1.0

"data" now includes  X y coordinates and the value. you should have all you need

Answer (score 0):

1. Read in the file and save all of the data into a 4 by n matrix as you said.
2. Then loop through each row and save the appropriate S or P value as array[F][T]=S

Comment: How can I go about this?